# Add div text to a input

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

How can I add a `div` content to a `input` using js

I have this code

```
<div>This is text</div>
<input type="text" name="test" id="inputs">
<button>Go</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you need to change the value of input to div's content on the button's click.

```js
const main = () => {
  // declare the variables
  const div = document.querySelector('div')
  const input = document.querySelector('input')
  const button = document.querySelector('button')
  
  // defining the click listener
  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    const divContent = div.innerText
    input.value = divContent
  }
  
  // attaching the `click` listener to button
  button.addEventListener('click', handleButtonClick)
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', main)
```

```html
<div>This is text</div>
<input type="text" name="test" id="inputs">
<button>Go</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', evt => {
  let str = document.querySelector('#inputs').value;
  document.querySelector('div').innerHTML += '<div>' + str + '</div';
});
```

```html
<div>This is text</div>
<input type="text" name="test" id="inputs">
<button>Go</button>
```